# Matches the starting position within the string in the Sublime text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I match starting position of the line by using `regular expression` in the Sublime text? (inverse of "\n")
For example I need insert `"+"` in the beginning of each lines.

**Before:**

```
First
Second
Third
```

**After:**

```
+First
+Second
+Third
```

I have tried to use `"\^"` but that didn't work

Comment: did you try `(?m)^` with `+` as replacement?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't `^` to replace with `+` work? Are you sure? What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find: `^(.*)`, replace with `+$1`.